# Convert array inside single quotes to a regular array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

'["value", {"label":"Value","type":"select","source":[["1","Yes"],["0","No"]]}]'

How do I convert this array inside single quotes to a regular arrayin PHP?

Comment: If it actually contains those singe quotes then use `trim($json, "'");`

Answer (score 1):

use [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

```
$string = '["value", {"label":"Value","type":"select","source":[["1","Yes"],["0","No"]]}]';

$phpArray = json_decode($string, true);

var_dump($phpArray);
```